# How to transfer control of a mouse operation when the button is still pressed

Tags: c#, winforms, mouseevent

I have a series of events for a `Panel` – `MouseDown` , `MouseMove` , `MouseUp`. I also have event handlers for a `Label` on that `Panel`. But in certain cases I want the `MouseMove`  handler of the `Label` to "transfer control" of the operation to the `Panel`'s handlers. Problem is that the action is "locked" to the `Label`, so something like `panel1.MouseMove += ...` won't help because the `panel1.MouseMove` won't be raised until a `MouseUp`. Is there any way to "transfer control" of the operation?

Here's a simple example of what I have: (`label1` is on `panel1`).

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    label1.MouseDown += label1_MouseDown;
}

void label1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    panel1.MouseMove += panel1_MouseMove;
}

void panel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Text = "success";
}
```

The Text isn't changed until MouseUp.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply call the `panel1_MouseMove` in `label1_MouseDown` when needed.

```
void label1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    panel1_MouseMove(null, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

Comment: +1. But my real app has two complex classes (-with many Mouse event handlers), one for the label and one for the panel. I'm trying to detach the operation completely from the Label. But I guess I wasn't clear in my formulation of the question.

Comment: You can un-subscribe from `label1_MouseUp` on `label1_MouseDown`and after `panel1_MouseDown` again subscribe to it. Something like `label1.MouseUp -= label1_MouseUp;`